# awk printf -x producing different output on different mawk versions

Tags: awk

Here is the problem.
Running:

```
echo '<position x="25" y="-9"/>' | awk -F '[="]' '{
printf ("%.2x", $6)
}'
```

produces different output on bash
`GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`
and
`GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

Output in
`Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS` `x86_64`

```
awk -W version

mawk 1.3.4 20200120
Copyright 2008-2019,2020, Thomas E. Dickey
Copyright 1991-1996,2014, Michael D. Brennan
```

:
00

Output in
`Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS` `x86_64`

```
awk -W version
mawk 1.3.3 Nov 1996, Copyright (C) Michael D. Brennan
```

:
fffffff7

I am expecting/need the output of the older version, how can I change my script to get the same result?

Comment: The example is incomplete (that '%' is not in the script), and the example produces sign-extended values for both gawk and mawk, in a quick test.  OP hasn't provided enough information to duplicate the results, unless of course this is a change in gawk which doesn't match bwk or mawk :-)

Comment: I'm looking at Debian 10, aside from the 32-bits with mawk 1.3.3, all of the others are 64 bits with sign-extension (however, the *current* mawk isn't in Ubuntu, so it's possible that there's some regression affecting Ubuntu and fixed since then...).  By the way "1.3.4" was a while back.  Ubuntu has 1.3.4.20200120

Comment: @ThomasDickey the % is in the output of my shell, it is not significant to the problem. Why do you say that the information provided is not enough? instead mention what more information would help

Comment: @Anand your OS, architecture, and the outputs of `awk -W version` in both cases please

Comment: updated question

Comment: In `mawk 1.3.4 20200120` the `d_to_U` function (which is used for unsigned format conversions `%o` and `%u` as well as `%x` and `%X`) appears to return 0 for negative values

Comment: yep, i get `00` from `mawk 1.3.4 20200120` on Debian Sid.   gawk  5.1.0 gives me 64 bit `fffffffffffffff7` and original-awk 20180827 gives me 32-bit `fffffff7`. Looks like a bug.

Comment: In that case, I apparently fixed it last year as part of a large series of changes which isn't complete.  If someone opens a bug report on Debian, I can probably backport a patch from that to address this problem.

Comment: Is this not reproducible by a simple `printf` invocation on a value, without the HTML tag being split on `"` and `=`?